# Div not rendering properly with external CSS file

Tags: php, html, css

I am programming a website, but I can have just one div per CSS document.

Here is my code:

```css
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
background-color: white;
background: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/160133/pexels-photo-160133.jpeg");
background-size: cover;
}
#menu {
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
background-color: white;
float: right;
}
#menu ul {
list-style: none;
margin-right: 25%;
}
#menu li {
padding-top: 7px;
float: right;
color: black;
display: inline;
margin-right: 15px;
font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}
#menu a {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}
#menu a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: #DD0604;
}
#menu li:hover::first-letter {
color: black;
}
#menu li::first-letter {
color: #DD0604;
}
#menu img {
width: 70px;
height: 70px;
margin-top: -25px;
}
/* This doesnt work */
.devices-and-text {
color: green;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Tvorba webstránok FAXEOT</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li style="float: left;  margin-left: 30%;"> <img src="images/logo.png"> </li>
      <li class="blue"><a href="#"> Menu </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Menu </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Menu </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Menu </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="devices-and-text">
    This text doesn't work...
  </div>
</body>
```

Website shows menu and everything about menu is OK. But my div "devices-and-text" is still black not green. When I put the style into the index.php, everything works.

Comment: is the file located correctly? maybe do either href="/css/main.css" or href="../css/main/.css"

Comment: Yes, for sure. The menu style is OK. I tried ..

Comment: It may be a location issue in the folder as well. Try this:`.devices-and-text {color: #00ff00;} `

Comment: does everything else on the page work from that style sheet and its this one class that isn't working?

Comment: You posted `style.css`, not `main.css`

Comment: Check your paths and file names for your CSS. Is there other CSS that's overriding the styles? When included properly [everything works](https://jsfiddle.net/1hbudyds/).

Comment: if you copy out the div and the css code by itself it works. So it has to be a path problem

Comment: When you put the style in `<style>` tags, WHERE do you do that? Same place as where the link is, or further below? Is it possible something else is being loaded that is overriding styles in your stylesheet? Have you tried increasing the specificity of your style (ie. `div.devices-and-text`), to see if its being overriden? @above comments: some of the styles are working, only this one isn't. Clearly not a path problem.

Comment: You are also missing `</html>`.

Comment: I checked the file locations. Add </html> but nothing change. There is not anything else with ending ".css". I tried to specificity the style. But still no change.

Comment: Please consider create a jsFiddler for your question. Probably you will find the issue during the jsFiddler creation.

Comment: When i create jsFiddler, everything is ok.

Comment: how is your folder structure set up... so like c:/mainproject/css/main.css

Comment: Its applications/xampp/htdocs/faxeot/css/main.css

Comment: maybe do a check first. copy the file into your c: drive so that its c:/main.css and copy that into your href="c:/main.css" and see if that works, if it does then its a path problem so you'll have to either copy the path exactly or start adding locations, ie: href="../faxeot/css/main.css", then href="../htdocs/faxeot/css/main.css" until it works

Comment: A little rusty on PHP and Xampp, but...right now Xampp is trying to load your CSS file from `htdocs/` and not `htdocs/faxeot/`. View your site at `localhost/faxeot/` and check Dev Tools, you should see the browser requesting `localhost/css/main.css`. What you want is `localhost/faxeot/css/main.css`. You can create a virtual host with Xampp to point static file requests to `localhost/faxeot/`. Otherwise, a HTML only solution will require you to use `faxeot/css/main.css`. Without a virtual host or defining a constant with PHP, moving files from local to production gets tricky (annoying).

Comment: Can you take a screen grab and post it in your answer?

Comment: I rename the css file, and everything works.